# Drupal create archive block

Tags: drupal, view, blogger, blogspot

Using Drupal CMS. Tell me please, how can I create an archive block like Blogger.

[image]

Standard Archive of Views module is not suitable. Considered the option of using Views Accordion - impossible groupping on multiple fields (month and year in this case). Think about writing a module, but still vague idea of how this can be realized: to provide module Views, or only Views Style Plugin ...

In general, waiting for offers.

Answer (score 3):

I just wrote a blog post on this: http://www.only10types.com/2010/12/drupal-collapsible-blog-archive-like.html

It runs through a simple implementation using Views and a bit of jQuery. It might not be exactly the same as the Blogger implementation, but after a lot of looking it's the best I've come up with.